# XFCE - keyboard configuration migration

Tags: linux, keyboard, xfce

where are the Xfce store keyboard configurations for a migration? I want to prepare the "startup" script to prepare newly installed Linux to match my preference and persistently set up a Czech keyboard for the user who runs it. I try lots of Google and documentation but sadly I can't find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try checking in `/usr/share/themes/Default/xfwm4/keythemerc` and `$HOME/.config/xfce4/`?

Comment: How about running `xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -lv > backup.txt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. All configurations for xfce4 keyboard are stored in the user home folder so it could be migrated to another machine.

Solution. The xfce store the keyboard configuration for a user at these files:

~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/keyboard-layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="keyboard-layout" version="1.0">
  <property name="Default" type="empty">
    <property name="XkbDisable" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <property name="XkbLayout" type="string" value="cz"/>   <-- required keyboard layout (cz = Czech)
    <property name="XkbVariant" type="string" value="bksl"/>  <-- required keyboard variant (bksl) name of variant with  <|> key
  </property>
</channel>
```

~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/keyboards.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel name="keyboards" version="1.0">
  <property name="Default" type="empty">
    <property name="Numlock" type="bool" value="true"/> <-- start with numlock on
  </property>
</channel>
```